# Lightning pop up on Opportunity Stage change

Tags: lightning

URGENT Requirement:

I am trying to display a custom pop up with Footer buttons, Ok and Cancel when the Opportunity Stage changes from Closed Won to Unqualified. I am using LDS (Lightning Data Service) to do so without Apex controller.
Issue:

- The pop up is loading everytime I refresh the page
  I only want the pop up to load **only** upon Stage change from CW to UQ and not when Opportunity is in Stage UQ.
  Please help fix this

My code
**WarningModal.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionwithoutheader" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="opportunityRecord" type="Opportunity"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
 <aura:attribute name="openModal" type="Boolean" default="false" />

      <force:recordData aura:id="opportunityRecordCmp"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Id,StageName"
                      targetFields="{!v.opportunityRecord}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.openModal}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}" 
                        mode="EDIT"/>

    <!-- Here we wrapped our modal code inside aura:if. If it evaluates true, code inside it will be visible -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.openModal}" >
        <div class="demo-only" style="height: 100px;">
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <!-- Header of Modal -->
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" class="slds-modal__close" size="small" variant="bare" alternativeText="Close" onclick="{! c.closeModal }"/>
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Warning</h2>
                    </header>
                     <!-- Body of Modal -->
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <p> Closed Won Opps are not recovered. Continue?</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Footer of Modal -->
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="OK" title="Save" onclick="{!c.handleOk}" />
                        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick="{! c.handleCancel }" />   
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- Backdrop to set background slightly opaque. -->
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
    <!--End of Modal Footer-->
     <!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
        <div class="recordError">
            <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" closable="true">
                {!v.recordError}
            </ui:message>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**WarningModal.js**

```
({
   
    openModal:function(component, event, helper) {
        var stageName=component.get("v.opportunityRecord");
        if(stageName.StageName=='Unqualified'){
           component.set('v.openModal',true);
        }
    },
             
 handleOk:function(component, event, helper) {
      
        component.set('v.openModal',false);

     },
    
    handleCancel : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.openModal',false);
    }
})
```

Please help fix this

Answer (score 0):

Update your openModal function as shown below:

```
openModal:function(component, event, helper) {
    var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
    
    if (changeType === "CHANGED" && (('StageName' in event.getParams().changedFields))) {
        var newStageName = event.getParams().changedFields.StageName.value;
        var oldStageName = event.getParams().changedFields.StageName.oldValue;
        if(newStageName == 'Unqualified' && oldStageName == 'Closed Won'){
            component.set('v.openModal',true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arut,Thanks for responding. I tried replacing the JS controller code as you mentioned. However, the pop up did't fire upon Stage change to Unqualified from Closed Won. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried placing few console.log statements to capture the values (inside & outside the IF loops)? Do the API names of the picklist values exactly match 'Unqualified' & 'Closed Won'?

Comment: Looks like the "initStageName" is not being set to Closed Won. I tried tweaking it but still couldn't get it to work. Would you be able to test this out and assist me with the workaround for the same?

Comment: Turns out that my earlier code snippet was incorrect. Try the updated code snippet and this should solve your problem. [No need to add any additional attribute in the component file]

Comment: Hi Arut, I've tried your updated code and the pop up seems to be working now upon Stage change!!! However, upon move from Closed Won to Unqualified, the pop up does show up but, the record is being saved to Unqualified before hitting Ok or cancel buttons on the Pop up. Do you know how I can prevent the default save from happening upon Stage change?

Comment: Also, the current record should only be saved onclick of OK button and should not save changes on click of Cancel button. Meaning, onCancel, the record should revert to the previous Stagename of Closed Won.

Comment: That's because 'openModal' is wired to 'recordUpdated' event of force:recordData and this event occurs after the record is updated. If you need to control the saving of record, then you can implement record edit form (or a custom HTML) leveraging the data fetched by recordData. Check out the last code sample here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_save_record.htm