# Handle Opportunity Stage change

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

Reuirement : To show the fields and their values BEFORE saving the opportunity ONLY when opportunity Stage is changed to 'closed WON'.

For this I'm trying to use the LWC along with lightning modal but I'm stuck on how to call the LWC component to do the same. I'm aware to call JS methods on custom buttons though but not sure how I can call the LWC method to do the same from 'Mark as Current Stage' standard button.

I was able to do the same from Aura using (link : [Lightning pop up on Opportunity Stage change](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317205/lightning-pop-up-on-opportunity-stage-change)) but running out of idea for LWC. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use wire service in LWC on the opportunity record page which will fire whenever there is a change in the Opportunity values.

In the wire service, you can add a check only to show the modal whenever the stage is changed to your desired change.

You can read about the wire service -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about

I'm using LDS to get opportunity values -

HTML -

```
<template>
    <template lwc:if={showModal}>
        <lightning-modal-header label="My Modal Heading"></lightning-modal-header>
            <lightning-modal-body>
                <h1>showing modal on stage change</h1>
            </lightning-modal-body>
            <lightning-modal-footer>
                <!-- Footer here --> 
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Close" title="Close" onclick={closeModal}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-modal-footer>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS -

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import STAGE from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';

export default class OpportunityStageChange extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    showModal=false;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [STAGE] })
    checkOpportunityStage({ error, data }) {
      if (data) {
        console.log('Data', data);
        console.log('OUTPUT : ', data.fields.StageName);
        if(data.fields.StageName.value === 'Closed Won'){
            this.showModal = open;
        }
      } else if (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    }

    closeModal(){
        this.showModal = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only going to fire from LDS after save, the question was related to before save

Comment: Thanks a lot Mukul, I'l also using same approach to do the same. Let's see how far I'll be able to get :)